# Windows 11 machine bricked by reducing the desktop resolution

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, windows-11

Windows 11 on a Dell XPS laptop had been fine until I reduced the resolution from the native laptop screen resolution of 3840 vertical by 2560 horizontal to a mere 1280x1024 to try an application out that I wanted to test at that resolution.
Once changed, the system became unstable, and I had to restart.  After restarting, it seems that the video driver (perhaps nvidia gtx 1050 laptop graphics or intel HD) does not like this resolution or is buggy, and Windows shell won't launch after I log in.  The video driver works well enough to log me in, and I am able to boot into safe mode only.  But once I reboot into non safe mode, the system is basically bricked.

It gets as far as logging into windows showing the spinny cursor for about an hour, then eventually gets to a black desktop with a mouse cursor that is moveable around. Ctrl Alt Delete does nothing.

Safe mode does work (although it's hard to get into because Microsoft hates the human race), but nothing I do in safe mode including removing drivers helps.

Is there an alternative to reinstalling or resetting windows to get it back to operational state?

Comment: You could try to uninstall the Nvidia driver from within Safe Mode, this likely would prevent the issue you experience

Comment: Note that "Bricked" refers to a problem that cannot be solved without sending hardware back to the manufacturer for servicing or replacement. the issue you describe, could be solved simply by reinstalling windows, if other less invasive options are insufficient.

Comment: The machine is, as far as many users would be concerned, unusable.  It seems that it's not a failure to boot, and not a hardware failure, but an account failure rendering desktop logins impossible. What single word is better?

Comment: Uninstalling drivers does not fix it, it appears to be a user-profile (registry hive for user, user home directory content) or microsoft account problem.  Removing and re-adding the account may be a lot less invasive and less work than a full windows reinstall.

Comment: @WarrenP, any general synonym for "not working" that doesn't have a more specific definition already should suffice. Sorry, not trying to nitpick, but since its in your title, it leads everyone to ask themselves "does this querant know what that word means?"